# How can I get the a key given a value in a Map<String, List<String>>?

Tags: java, dictionary, java-stream

Given a Map with the following structures `{group2=[form4], group1=[form1, form2, form3]}` how can I get the key(groupN) based on a value(formN)? Basically if one of the entries has a match with my input form I want to get that entry's key to set as the new form.

I was thinking of something like this:

```
newForm= formAliasList.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .filter(entry -> form.toLowerCase().equals(entry.getValue()))
        .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
        .findFirst().get();
```

Comment: For a large dataset that's going to be an expensive operation.  If you need to perform this search a large number of times, build a reverse map one time that maps `{form1=[group1,...], form2=[group1,...], ... , form4=[group1,...]}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the value in `Map<String, List<String>>` is `List<String>`, you can simply check the `formN` existed in `List` using contains, and then collect the key of entry

```
newForm = formAliasList.entrySet()
                      .stream()
                      .filter(entry -> entry.getValue().contains(form.toLowerCase()))
                      .findFirst().map(Map.Entry::getKey).orElse(null);
```